# Are least square solutions maintained?

Tags: least-squares, pseudoinverse

If I have a least squares problem $AXB = C$ for $X$, where $BB^+ = I$ ($B^+$ being the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse). Does this last property make it so that the first least sqaures problem and the adapted least squares problem $AX = CB^+$ have the same solution for $X$? I consider only matrices with real values and of dimensions appropriate for the stated problems and properties.